# Feed Keras batches of data then do multiple epochs worth of training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset of around 980 lines (each with 12 features and a category variable), and I want to carry out an n-fold cross validation on this set. To do this what I am doing currently is partitioning the dataset into `n` sets, saving the index of the currently delegated test set (I start with 0 and iterate it up to `n`) then feeding my keras model each partition (that isnt the test set) via `train_on_batch()`. What I seem to be having issues with, is that I can't do epochs this way. For `fit()`, I would need to

1. Partition the dataset into `n` sets
2. Delegate the index of a test set
3. Then create the train dataset by concating all **but** the test set back together.

Step (3) seems extremely silly to do, which is the reason I tried to do it this way - is it possible to manually feed batches to the model and then train for `x` epochs?

Current code (only relevant sections):

```
def partition(self, chunks):
    temp_data = self.data
    temp_data[temp_data=="Normal"] = 0
    temp_data[temp_data=="Abnormal"] = 1
    partitions = np.array_split(temp_data, 10)
    return partitions

def nfold_cv(self, chunks, ep_each):
    parts = self.partition(chunks)
    testPartition = 0
    #Lets assign first set as test first, then use other 9 as train
    while testPartition < chunks:
        #Build new model for each iteration
        self.model = Sequential()
        self.model.add(Dense(units=self.neurons, input_shape=(12,)))
        for j in range(self.hidden):
            self.model.add(Dense(units=self.neurons, activation=self.hidden_activation, input_dim=(996,)))
        self.model.add(Dense(units=1, activation=self.end_activation))
        self.model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
        #Then iterate through all partitions and train on all that arent assigned as test partition
        for i in range(0, len(parts)):
            if testPartition != i:
                tempPart = parts[i].transpose()
                train_x = tempPart[1:,].transpose()
                train_y = tempPart[0]
                self.history = self.model.train_on_batch(train_x, train_y, reset_metrics=False )
        #Network is trained, now predict on assigned test partition
        test = parts[testPartition].transpose()
        test_x = test[1:,].transpose()
        test_y = test[0]
        predicted = self.model.predict(test_x)
        score = self.model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose=2)
        #Accuracy of this
        print("CV on test set at " + str(testPartition) + " is " + str(score[1]))
        #Assign next partition as test
        testPartition = testPartition + 1
```

Which creates an output like

```
CV on test set at 0 is 0.6000000238418579
CV on test set at 1 is 0.5400000214576721
CV on test set at 2 is 0.4699999988079071
CV on test set at 3 is 0.5099999904632568
CV on test set at 4 is 0.5199999809265137
CV on test set at 5 is 0.5600000023841858
CV on test set at 6 is 0.5858585834503174
CV on test set at 7 is 0.5252525210380554
CV on test set at 8 is 0.4747474789619446
CV on test set at 9 is 0.5656565427780151
```

using `n=10` for now

Comment: This may help in what you are trying to achieve https://www.kaggle.com/stefanie04736/simple-keras-model-with-k-fold-cross-validation

Comment: @Raj from what I understand this still contains the entire train dataset in one array, rather than multiple subsets